# How to delete completely duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

Say i have duplicate rows in my table and well my database design is of 3rd class :-

```
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Cinthol','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Cinthol','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Cinthol','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Lux','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (1,'Crowning Glory','cosmetic soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (2,'Cinthol','nice soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (3,'Lux','nice soap','soap');
Insert Into tblProduct (ProductId,ProductName,Description,Category) Values (3,'Lux','nice soap','soap');
```

I want only 1 instance of each row should be present in my table. Thus `2nd, 3rd and last row` whcih are completely identical should be deleted. What query can i write for this? Can it be done without creating temp tables? Just in one single query?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The first record based on insertion order?  For what version of SQL Server?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you mean 3rd normal form when you say 3rd class. If it's allowing complete duplicates in a table, it's not in 3NF by definition ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this - it will delete all duplicates from your table:

```
;WITH duplicates AS
(
    SELECT 
       ProductID, ProductName, Description, Category,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID, ProductName
                          ORDER BY ProductID) 'RowNum'
    FROM dbo.tblProduct
)
DELETE FROM duplicates
WHERE RowNum > 1
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.tblProduct
GO
```

Your duplicates should be gone now: output is:

```
ProductID   ProductName   DESCRIPTION        Category
   1          Cinthol         cosmetic soap      soap
   1          Lux             cosmetic soap      soap
   1          Crowning Glory  cosmetic soap      soap
   2          Cinthol         nice soap          soap
   3          Lux             nice soap          soap
```

Comment: Nice Marc_s, is this a CTE query? If so, is it not necessary in CTE query to have a `union` clause?

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal: yes, CTE's are one of the underused features of SQL Server - as is the OVER() clause :-)

Comment: +1: I wasn't sure that you could issue a delete against a CTE like that, and before I could test it you had your answer posted :)

Comment: @Tom H. Even i wasn't sure that Delete could be issued in CTE. I was under the impression that CTE's are only used for recursive queries.

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE tblProduct 
FROM tblProduct 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(ProductId) as ProductId, ProductName, Description, Category
   FROM tblProduct 
   GROUP BY ProductName, Description, Category
) as KeepRows ON
   tblProduct.ProductId= KeepRows.ProductId
WHERE
   KeepRows.ProductId IS NULL
```

Stolen from [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

**UPDATE:**

This will only work if ProductId is a Primary Key (which it is not).  You are better off using @marc_s' method, but I'll leave this up in case someone using a PK comes across this post.

Comment: @Abe: `rowid` was the primary key for the table; I thought this was Oracle syntax for a moment till I saw the link.

Comment: I was assuming that ProductId was a primary key in his table.  I've updated it with his column names to help avoid any confusion.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, i thought it would work but it did sound confusing to me. So i tested in Managemenet Studio and indeed it is not working. It says 0 rows deleted. Can you fix the query?

Comment: @Nitesh, I assumed (mistakenly) that ProductId would be a unique identifier.  Since it is not you are better off using @marc_s' method.  Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this a few weeks back... what version of SQL Server are you using?  In SQL Server 2005 and up, you can use Row_Number as part of your select, and only select where Row_Number is 1.  I forget the exact syntax, but it's well documented... something along the lines of:

```
Select t0.ProductID, 
       t0.ProductName, 
       t0.Description, 
       t0.Category
Into   tblCleanData
From   (
    Select ProductID, 
           ProductName, 
           Description, 
           Category, 
           Row_Number() Over (
               Partition By ProductID, 
                            ProductName, 
                            Description, 
                            Category
               Order By     ProductID,
                            ProductName,
                            Description,
                            Category
           ) As RowNumber
    From   MyTable
) As t0
Where t0.RowNumber = 1
```

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx, that should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First use a `SELECT... INTO`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, ProductName, Description, Category
    INTO tblProductClean
    FROM tblProduct
```

The drop the first table.

Comment: From the OP: "Can it be done without creating temp tables? Just in one single query?"