# How can I delete these rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

my columns in a table like this

```
column1  column2
100       1
100       1
101       2
101       3
102       4
102       5
103       6
104       7
104       7
```

and I want the output like this

```
column1 column2
101       2
101       3
102       4
102       5
103       6
```

Comment: how did you get below output?? what algorithm are you following?? Also what have you tried and where are you facing problem??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete completely duplicate rows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3345268/953140)

Comment: This is a question of sql server 2008

Comment: hey man , you want to `delete` , `select` or both ?!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table
(
  c1 int,
  c2 int
)

insert into @T values
(100,       1),
(100,       1),
(101,       2),
(101,       3),
(102,       4),
(102,       5),
(103,       6),
(104,       7),
(104,       7)

;with C as
(
  select count(*) over(partition by C1, C2) as D
  from @T
)
delete from C
where D > 1
```

Comment: I do not agree with your naming convention: `C` would be a more natural choice of a name for `COUNT(*)`, than `D`, and, to avoid possible confusion, the `C` CTE could be named `E`! Just joking :) This is a(nother) great example of using a CTE actually!

Comment: @AndriyM - Ok, I will work a bit in names :). I guess `D` in this case could be short for `DuplicateCount`. `C` is actually an excellent name when it is a derived table of the table `T` :).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a query to return the rows without repeats, you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2
FROM MyTable
```

If you **actually** want to delete the rows, then follow @Ahamed's link to [a previous SO answer on deleting duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345268/how-to-delete-completely-duplicate-rows)

Comment: It will not works. Please see the query carefully, Its not so that easy

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you only want rows whose column2's value is between 2 and 6

```
Delete from your_table
Where column2<2 or column2>6
```

Now you will be left only with the rows you want, you can just select all now:

```
Select column1, column2
From yourtable
```

Comment: or `Delete from your_table
Where column in (1,7)`